# Extend typed array class in Typescript

Tags: typescript, typed-arrays

I would like to extend a Javascript-typed array in Typescript. Specifically, I want to start with a regular Uint8Array and then initialize it with 1's (instead of 0's as per regular typed array) and add some extra methods. I would like to do this in a way such that the regular ways of instantiating typed arrays don't throw type errors, e.g. `new SpecialArray([1, 2, 3])` and `new SpecialArray(3)` should both work as expected.

I've got something like this:

```ts
class SpecialArray extends Uint8Array {

   constructor(arg: number | number[]) {
      super(arg)
      this.fill(1)
   }
   
   ...

}
```

However, Typescript throws the following error about `arg`:

```
No overload matches this call.
  The last overload gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'number | number[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ArrayBufferLike'.
      Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'ArrayBufferLike'.ts(2769)
```

I found out I can get around this by using type assertions in the call to super:

```ts
super(arg as unknown as ArrayBufferLike)
```

However, this feels messy. Is there some clean way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Or more simply, use the built-in [`ConstructorParameters`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#constructorparameterstype) type:

```
class SpecialArray extends Uint8Array {
   constructor(...args: ConstructorParameters<typeof Uint8Array>) {
      super(...args)
      this.fill(1)
   }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDKAOBTYBLMICCAnLYCe0iAHgC6IB2AJjAKorkkAc2uBA3gLABQ0vwA9uQgksAV2Al+WABQA6eWCwBzCAC5oAYUHCxEqQAVFYALaIyWCAB4SeJPwBm0Og2Y58APgCU0Tj17+IUSQZeVlFFU9uf38SAAsUCFl7FBAQaQBGSL9oAF9uHKA)

Comment: Learn something new every day. How did I miss that? Gold!

Answer (score 1):

The error gave a good hint. There is no version of `Uint8Array` that has a constructor taking `number | number[]`.

Try

```js
class SpecialArray extends Uint8Array {
  constructor(array: ArrayLike<number> | ArrayBufferLike) {
    super(array);
    this.fill(1)
  }
}
```